# SqlDataConnection type provider generates massive error with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, f#, sql-server-2008-r2, type-providers

For some reason, I can't create a type provider for a particular database. I have code which looks a bit like this (not the actual database names, obviously):

```ml
type db1 = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=SQL_05;Initial Catalog=**DATABASE1**;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True">
type db2 = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=SQL_08;Initial Catalog=**DATABASE2**;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True">
type db3 = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=SQL_10;Initial Catalog=**DATABASE3**;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True">
```

The first 2 lines are totally fine, my program was working fine as long as those were the only databases I needed. However, once I added the third line, I got a single, huge error along these lines:

```
The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error:  
tmp7AA1.cs(12,7): warning CS0437: The type 'System' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7AA1.cs' conflicts with the imported namespace 'System' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll'. Using the type defined in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7AA1.cs'.
tmp7AA1.cs(88967,22): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
tmp7AA1.cs(12,7): error CS0138: A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System' is a type not a namespace
tmp7AA1.cs(88967,22): (Location of symbol related to previous error)tmp7AA1.cs(13,7): 
warning CS0437: The type 'System' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7AA1.cs' conflicts with the imported namespace 'System' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll'. Using the type defined in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7AA1.cs'.
tmp7AA1.cs(88967,22): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
tmp7AA1.cs(88967,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'INotifyPropertyChanging' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
tmp7AA1.cs(88967,56): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'INotifyPropertyChanged' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
tmp7AA1.cs(13,14): error CS0426: The type name 'Collections' does not exist in the type 'System'
tmp7AA1.cs(14,7): warning CS0437: The type 'System' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7AA1.cs' conflicts with the imported namespace 'System' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll'. Using the type defined in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7AA1.cs'.
tmp7AA1.cs(88967,22): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
tmp7AA1.cs(14,14): error CS0426: The type name 'ComponentModel' does not exist in the type 'System'
```

And so on, for **116460 lines!**

I can connect to each server in SSMS to verify that these connection strings work. Here's what I see:

- `SQL_05` is version 10.0.2531  (SQL Server 2008)
- `SQL_08` is version 10.0.2500  (SQL Server 2008)
- `SQL_10` is version 10.50.4286 (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Other than this, I can't see any difference between the three servers. Is there something I'm missing here? Do I need to add some reference to be able to create a type provider for this particular server?

Comment: I suspect a typo.....

Comment: @MitchWheat I've gone over it numerous times, with several variations thinking the same thing. When I intentionally screw up the connection string, I get "The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error: Error reading schema. Error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server..."

Comment: Have you tried using [SqlEntityConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh362322.aspx) instead of SqlDataConnection to see if that has the same issue?

Comment: Any solutions to this? I'm getting the same error for a specific database. Works with all other databases on the same server, except with one. Not sure how it's related.