# How to create SqlDataConnection for db with table 'System'?

Tags: sql-server, f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

I want to create a `SqlDataConnection` type provider for a database with a table, which name is exactly 'System'.

During compilation I get an error:

> The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported     an error: 
>       tmpB600.cs(12,7): warning CS0437: The type 'System' in     'c:\Users\krajewa1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpB600.cs' conflicts with the imported namespace     'System' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll'. Using     the type defined in 'c:\Users\krajewa1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpB600.cs'.
>       [...] (hundreds of errors following)

To workaround it I've tried :

- Using `LocalSchemaFile` with dbml file which does not contain 'System'
  table. It did not help, still the same error.
- Using `ContextTypeName` parameter (which I hoped would put types in another namespace). It did not help, still the same error.
- Creating a synonym for System table. Of course original table was still there, so I got the same error.
- Obviously, changing table name to '_System' does help, but is not feasible in practice in my case.

My problem is exactly the same as the one asked in this question:

[SqlDataConnection type provider generates massive error with SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918148/sqldataconnection-type-provider-generates-massive-error-with-sql-server-2008-r2).

However, in that thread users did not the find real cause of the problem and did not provide an answer.

Comment: never tried but I think if you just don't "open System"?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to fix this, but you can try the open-source SQL type provider instead of the standard one: http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/

Comment: I don't know F# but if this is a SQL Server backend and you can't rename the [System] Table could you create an alias on SQL Server allowing you to refer to it by an additional name? Or even just CREATE VIEW SystemTable as Select * FROM System and use the view instead?

Comment: @Carsten König, in my example I do not have "open System"

Comment: @TomasPetricek Type provider that you pointed works in this case. I was not aware that other implementation exists. Thank you very much. In practice it solves my problem, because I am not tied in any way to standard type provider.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know F# but could you not create a SQL Server synonym for the problematic table name?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177544.aspx

```
CREATE SYNONYM [SystemTable] for [System]
```

And then refer to the table by the synonym instead of it's real name in your F# Code.

It might be possible to simply rename the table instead but if there are any other queries running against it they would need to be changed as well. The synonym means both names are valid

Comment: This is clever idea, I forgot about synonyms during analysis. Unfortunately it does not fix the error, since original table 'System' is still present and type provider still tries to include it. Nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: You could rename the table and then create a synonym in the other direction so that now the new name would be the real name and the old name would be the synonym. That way existing code that refers to [System] would work but [System] wouldn't appear on the list of tables

Comment: That is great idea and it actually allows usage of standard sql type provider. Thanks. I am not sure if it possible in my case (whether I will be able to change database schema), but nevertheless it is one step closer to ideal.